# Jquery Validation doesn't validate when input is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a form that is using jquery validation and it works great except for this one issue. To reproduce the issue, fill in all fields in the form, and then choose fields randomly and removed the input. Continue doing so until an error message does not appear at the top, thats the problem.

I'm not sure why it doesn't validate the fields when the input is removed. If anyone can show me why it's doing this, that would be great. I can't reproduce it on any of the Demos on the jquery validate website so I think it has something to do with the way I have mine set up.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/07jm89wp/6/)**

```
$.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
      return this.optional(element) || value != param;
    });

$("#wizardForm").validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required:{
                depends:function(){
                    $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
                    return true;
                }
            },
            pattern: /^[a-zA-Z]+([\s]+)?['-]?([a-zA-Z]+)?$/
        },
        lastname: {
            required: {
                depends:function(){
                    $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
                    return true;
                }
            },
            pattern: /^[a-zA-Z]+([\s]+)?['-]?([a-zA-Z]+)?$/
        },
        email: {
            required: {
                depends:function(){
                    $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
                    return true;
                }
            },
            email: true,
            notEqual: "demo@somewhere.com",
            pattern: /^(.)+(@)(.)+[.](.)+$/
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: {
                param: "#PWconfirm",
                depends: function(element) {
                  return $("#wizardForm #PWconfirm").val();
                }
            }
        },
        PWconfirm: {
            required: true
        },
        company: {
            required: true
        },   
        zip: {
            required: true
        },         
        country: "required"
    },
    errorLabelContainer: ".validation-error-msg",
    wrapper: "li",
    errorClass: "validation-error",
    messages: {
        firstname: {
            required: "The 'First Name' field cannot be empty.",
            pattern: "The 'First Name' field must not contain numbers or special characters."
        },
        lastname: {
            required: "The 'Last Name' field cannot be empty.",
            pattern: "The 'Last Name' field must not contain numbers or special characters."
        },
        email: {
            required: "The 'Email Address' field cannot be empty.",
            email: "The 'Email Address' must be in a valid email format.",
            notEqual: "This email address is reserved, please use another.",
            pattern: "The 'Email Address' must be in a valid email format."
        },
        password: {
            required: "The 'Password' field cannot be empty.",
            equalTo: "Password fields do not match!"
        },
        company: "The 'Company Name' field cannot be empty.",
        zip: "The 'Zip Code' field cannot be empty.",
        PWconfirm: "The 'Retype Password' field cannot be empty.",
        country: "The 'Country' field needs a valid selection."
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: It seems to be working fine with any input value being removed randomly. do you have the exact scenario when it happens ?

Comment: It's happening pretty consistently for me when I fill in every field, then remove the retype password, then last name. I'm also doing this in Chrome.

Comment: Your fiddle work fine.

Comment: Your fiddle is working for me too.  Although, your usage of the `depends` property is **very unusual**.  I suspect this to be the root source of your problem.

Comment: I'm still seeing the issue, however it does appear to be intermittent now. Here I removed the `depends` property that @Sparky was concerned about and I still am seeing the problem. I should note I am never clicking the submit button. Fill in all the fields and then take out some random fields. [New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/07jm89wp/7/)

Comment: "Intermittent" problems are unusual for this plugin.  Either it works or it doesn't.  Typically, one misunderstands [the default behavior](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo) and mistakes that for a problem.  Your new jsFiddle is also working exactly as designed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quote OP's Comment:**

> I should note I am never clicking the submit button. Fill in all the fields and then take out some random fields.

It's called "lazy validation".  It's how the plugin was designed to work.  Basically, errors for empty fields are ignored until the submit button is clicked the first time.

See [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo):

> Before a field is marked as invalid, the validation is lazy: Before submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through fields without getting annoying messages – they won't get bugged before having the chance to actually enter a correct value

Comment: This makes sense. I definitely misunderstood the default behavior and thought it to be a problem. Thanks for the explanation and the links to documentation.